Is there a way to validate time being input on Google Forms?
At work we have a Production Form that is filled out in Google Forms, on this form there is a "start time" and "end time" questions. These are not entered necessarily live, so at times based off the workstream they're working, end users may fill out 2-3 of these at a time.
The form has 'questions' with Time answers, these pre-populate with AM selected by default as all Google Forms do, so it's easy for end users to input a start of lets say... 11:00 AM, of which they've only typed in the "11:00" portion, and go to type an End Time of "2:00" PM but forget to change the AM to PM, thus causing the issue.
Is there anyway to have data validation/ some sort of check occur for the End User to see, if the shift time being entered is longer then lets say 8 hours a window pops up a question "are you sure you want to enter a shift time longer then 8 hours" or something along those lines?
I created a quick simplified version and attached a photo to make sure I explained the Time fields properly.
example img
I wasn't able to get very far reviewing past questions

I created a quick simplified version and attached a photo Did you forget to include them in the question? BTW, the question is tagged Excel; is there a specific content for that or would that be oversight?

Hmm, yes to both. Thanks for the call out, post edited.

I am happy to stand corrected but, to the best of my belief, Google Forms does not include a feature that would (in real time) validate the responses to two DateTime questions and display a message if required prior to submitting the form response. Of course, doing this after the form is submitted is possible but arguably less effective. OTOH, you may wish to research whether there is an add-on that provides this feature.

I am with Tedinoz with this one. You can open your question by editting it to be more flexible in terms of accepting different type of answers.  There are numerous ways to actually make this happen and everything involves creating your own form to fill out utilizing Google Apps Script - Web Apps.
